# Приложение-звонилка. Как реализовать звонок в фоне?

Tags: android, android-studio

У дома поставили 2 шлагбаума. Чтобы их открыть нужно совершить звонок на один из двух номеров. Пишу приложение, которое по нажатию на кнопки открывает нужный. Пока смог реализовать звонок через `Intent.ACTION_CALL`, но при этом на экран вылезает штатная звонилка. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы звонок совершался в фоновом режиме?

Comment: Зачем делать отбой звонка, если шлагбаум сам его сбрасывает?

Comment: Когда я узнал, что шлагбаум сам сбрасывает звонок, я дописал, что отбой звонка больше не нужен. Читайте вопрос до конца.

Comment: Я дочитал. Если вопрос не актуален, то удалите его.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение - после запроса на звонок вызываю `MainActivity` через `Intent`. Из самого активити сделать это не удалось, видимо потому что оно становится неактивным во время звонка. Поэтому я запускаю сервис, из него вызываю `MainActivity`и сразу останавливаю этот сервис. Если кому интересно, вот код сервиса:

```
    public class OpenGatesService extends Service {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
            public void onFinish() {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.OpenGates");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                stopSelf();
            }
        }.start();
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Вызов активити делаю через секунду, т.к. без таймера похоже, что звонилка не успевает запуститься до вызова моего приложения и в итоге все равно вылезает на первый план. А может, у меня телефон просто тормозной:)

Answer (score 0):

Нет, позвонить вы сможете только с помощью Intent.ACTION_CALL

Без использования Intent позвонить невозможно. Это ограничение SDK.

Comment: Допустим. Но вопросов это не снимает. Возможно ли запустить звонилку в свернутом виде и как принудительно завершить звонок? Желательно по событию начала самого звонка, но можно и по времени. Я нашел решение с помощью интерфейса ITelephony и метода endCall(), но оно у меня почему-то не заработало:( Причем метод отрабатывался, но звонок не завершался. Возможно причина в том, что я не смог прописать в манифесте <receiver> вне тега <application>. На одноименном англоязычном ресурсе я нашел, что эта проблема встречается от версии к версии. То есть ее то исправляют, то опять появляется.

Comment: @SergeyGarbuz скорее всего эта лазейки была на более ранних версиях android, потом ее пофиксили.

Comment: @SergeyGarbuz я же сказал, что ты не сможешь запустить звонилку в свернутом виде, ибо тебя будет перекидывать всегда(если юзать с помощью Intent) на стандартную-встроенную звонилку.

Comment: Может я как-то непонятно объяснил... Я не отказываюсь от использования стандартной звонилки. Вот нажимаю я кнопку в своем приложении, открывается звонилка и набирает номер. Если я нажму на телефоне кнопку Home, то все приложения свернутся, в том числе и звонилка, хотя звонок будет продолжаться. Вот я хочу добиться этого программно, только чтоб не все приложения сворачивались, а только звонилка и мое приложение осталось на экране.

Comment: Из документации: переопределение кнопки Home запрещено системой.

Comment: Использование Home я как пример привел. Эмулировать нажатие этой кнопки, а потом разворачивать свою активность - так себе выход. Надеюсь, что есть более простое и подходящее решение.